# How to write unit test case for volley JSON request

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-volley

I've written unit test case for volley post request which doesn't seems to be work.I'm not getting response 
Below is my code

```
    final JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject();
    final CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    jsonobj.put(Constants.Params.SEARCH_STRING, "CBRE");
    jsonobj.put(Constants.Params.KEY_APP_CODE,Constants.Params.APP_CODE_VALUE);
    jsonobj.put(Constants.Params.KEY_CLIENT, Constants.Params.CLIENT_VALUE);
    jsonobj.put(Constants.Params.KEY_APPLICATION, Constants.Params.APPLICATION_VALUE);
    jsonobj.put(Constants.Params.KEY_LANGUAGE, Constants.Params.LANGUAGE_VALUE);
    jsonobj.put(Constants.Params.DORMANT_INCLUDE, String.valueOf(false));
    jsonobj.put(Constants.Params.DELETED_INCLUDE, String.valueOf(false));

    String url = Constants.Url.API_DOMAIN + Constants.Url.API_VERSION + Constants.Url.API_SEARCH_STRING + "PageNumber=1";

     JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonobj, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
        {
             System.out.print(response);
            STRING_BUILDER = new StringBuilder();
            STRING_BUILDER.append(response.toString());
            countDownLatch.countDown();

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            System.out.print(error.getMessage());
            countDownLatch.countDown();
        }
    });

    fakeRequestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

    countDownLatch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // wait for callback
    assertNotNull(STRING_BUILDER);
```

What I'm missing any help?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a problem with your fakeRequestQueue.If your fakeRequestQueue is properly defined then the test case should work. You can use a MockedQueue for creating a  fakeRequestQueue.